# Fix automatic lines in GVIM

Tags: vim, tcl

I'm writing script in TCL and want to know, how can I fix the beginning of each line automatic?
each line begin is different tab amount and I want to fix it automatically?

In Emacs I know I can press TAB each line to reorder start line position.
How can I do it in GVIM?

Comment: That might help you: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Fix_indentation

Comment: Along with that:
https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/tcl.vim .

What you want to do is install the syntax file (probably under `~/.vim/syntax/`), restart vim, and use the command provided by the wiki (`gg=G`)

Comment: Also you can use `>` and `<` to indent and deindent.

Comment: Can you further describe the problem you're having with indentation? Is Vim indenting your code unexpectedly? Or not indenting it and you'd like it to? Can you give an example code block, show how you expected it to look like?

Comment: Thanks all, indentation work but not properly. The first line shifted by 1 tab and the second shifted by 2 tabs.

My codes after identification.

`foreach bbox [get_property $var] bbox] {
set xy1 [lrange $bbox 0 1]
    set xy2 [lrange $bbox 2 3]
    ruler "\{\{${xy1}\} \{${xy2}\}\}"

}`

Comment: The code at the top of https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Reformatting+Tcl+code+indentation may help.